# The graph of a smooth map is a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Here is a problem from Guillemin-Pollack:

> The graph of a map $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is the subset of $X\times Y$
>   defined by $$graph(f)=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}.$$ Define $F: X\rightarrow
>  graph(f)$ by $F(x)=(x,f(x))$. Show that if $f$ is smooth, $F$ is a
>   diffeomorphism; thus $graph(f)$ is a manifold if $X$ is.

(Note that the notion of a manifold in this book is defined as follows: a subset of $R^k$ is a manifold of dimension $n$ if every points admits a neighborhood diffeomorphic to an open subset of $R^n$. For the definition of a smooth map see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607198/the-smoothness-of-a-product-map) question.)

Assume $X \subset R^k$ (as remarked above, only subsets of $R^k$ are considered in the book). My idea is to regard $F$ as the composition of $X\rightarrow X\times X \rightarrow graph(f), x\mapsto (x,x)\mapsto (x,f(x))$. The first map $x\mapsto (x,x)$ is smooth because it extends by the same formula to a smooth map $R^k\rightarrow R^k\times R^k$ and agrees with the original map on $X$. The second map $(x,x)\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is smooth by [The smoothness of a product map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607198/the-smoothness-of-a-product-map).

Further, the first map is clearly bijective and its inverse, $(x,x)\mapsto x$, is smooth since it extends by the same formula to a smooth map $R^k\times R^k\rightarrow R^k$.  The second map is also bijective with inverse $X\times f(X)\rightarrow X\times X,\ (x,f(x))\mapsto (x,x)$. But why is the inverse smooth? Now we cannot extend it to a smooth map $R^k\times R^k\rightarrow R^k\times R^k$ by the same formula anymore...

Comment: What does the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) tell you?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: in the book, the theorem is introduced after the problem is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $(x,f(x))\mapsto (x,x)$ can be viewed as the composition of the projection map $\operatorname{proj}_1\colon(x,f(x))\mapsto x$ and the diagonal map, both of which are smooth.

Comment: By "product" you mean "composition", right?

Comment: @user500094 yes

Comment: But why is the projection smooth? I think I'm stuck at this proof exactly at the same point as in my question. This map $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$ cannot be extended to a smooth map $R^k\times R^k\rightarrow R^k$ by the same formula (like I did in the preceding points in my question) since $f(X)\ne R^k$.

Comment: @user500094 I don't understand what you mean about extending to a smooth map... projection is already a smooth map on all of $\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to view it as a longer composition $\operatorname{graph}(f)\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: The projection is very nicely approximated by a linear map, it's already linear!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstand something. I was trying to use the definition stated at the link in my question to prove that the projection map is smooth (according to Pollack-Guillemin definition). The projection is a map from a subset of $R^{2k}$ to $R^k$. The definition says that such a map is smooth if it can be locally extended to a smooth map on open sets. I was trying to apply an equivalent version of this definition (definition 1 from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572813/smooth-map-on-a-non-open-subset?rq=1).

Comment: @user500094 Projection is not a map from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$, it is a map from _all_ of $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$, and so you don't need find an extension to an open set. But do you have to show that the restriction to $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ is smooth?

Comment: Probably I used the word "projection" incorrectly. What I meant is the projection from the graph of $f$ to $R^k$, i.e., the restriction of the projection $R^{2k}\rightarrow R^k$ to the graph of $f$. To prove that this restricted projection is smooth, we need to extend it to a smooth map on open sets. It is not extendable to a map on the whole $R^{2k}$, so I was (and am) not sure how to extend it thereby proving the smoothness of the restricted projection.

Comment: @user500094 Well, since $\operatorname{proj}_1$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^k$ it may certainly be "extended" to any open set therein. More explicitly, let $(x_0,f(x_0))\in\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^k.$ Let $U\times V$ be an open neighborhood of $(x_0,f(x_0))$. Then $\operatorname{proj}_1$ may be extened to all of $U\times V$ as $\operatorname{proj}_1(u,v)=u.$ Is this what you have in mind?