# Graph of a density over one Riemannian manifold itself a Riemannian manifold? And follow up questions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Intuitively it seemed natural to me that the graph of a density $p(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a manifold. After a little bit of searching I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607255/the-graph-of-a-smooth-map-is-a-manifold), which I believe(?) confirms my intuition. Call this manifold $\mathcal{M}$.

The follow up questions are:

1. Since $p(x)$ is measurable, does it naturally induce a measure on $\mathcal{M}$ through push-forward measure? If so, is this measure uniform on $\mathcal{M}$?
2. Conversely, for the uniform/standard measure on a given Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ (with necessary assumptions on $\mathcal{M}$ such as smoothness, compactness, etc.), is there any mapping to $\mathbb{R}^n$ where this uniform density also is transformed to a density on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
3. Can we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an arbitrary manifold, and then would the results still follow?

I apologize if these questions are obvious, and they're answered somewhere that I am not aware of. I would appreciate any pointers if that's the case. Also sorry if my use of terms are sloppy. I am doing my best, mathematics not being my main area of research these days.

Comment: What does it mean for a measure on $\mathcal{M}$ to be uniform? And could you define "density" in this context?

Comment: To addresss your (?), yes: assuming $p : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, the graph $\{(x,p(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ is indeed a manifold, and it will be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk thanks for answering (?) and apologies, I meant the standard/uniform measure on a Riemannian manifold. It is the bread and butter in papers on manifold regularization. For example see page 2405, Remark 1, Item 1 in: https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/belkin06a/belkin06a.pdf

Comment: And from what I can understand it refers to the natural measure defined using the metric on the Riemannian manifold.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Then the question becomes: which Riemannian metric are you giving to $\mathcal{M}$? Are you pulling back on the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ along the canonical diffeomorphism $(x, p(x)) \mapsto x : \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}^n$? If so, the answer is yes -- the pushforward of the Riemannian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be the Riemannian measure on $\mathcal{M}$ with respect to the Riemannian metric on $\mathcal{M}$ induced by the diffeomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is basically by definition of "Riemannian measure".

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers. Could you also please tell me a reference that I could see these things written? That indeed (from what I understand through your replies) the Lebesgue measure leads to the "uniform measure" on the graph $(x, p(x))$ which is defined by the metric induced by the diffeomorphism $(x, p(x))$. Also could you pelase write this as an answer so I could accept it? Thanks so much!