# Smooth function on non open set question

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation, differential-topology

I have a question. In particular it concerns the answer to the following question:

[Smooth map on a "non-open" subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572813/smooth-map-on-a-non-open-subset/2572835#comment8477634_2572835)

Shouldn't one extend $F_x$ to $U$ ? How does one achieve this?

Note that the bump function argument only guarantees that we may get a smooth map defined on $U$ that agrees with $F_x$ on a possibly smaller neighborhood. So how does one remedy this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't actually necessary to extend $F_x$. This question is getting at a point which is more or less the reason that bump functions are used:

Let $U\subset M$ be an open subset, $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. If $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset U$, $f$ can always be smoothly extended to $M$, namely by defining
$$
\widetilde{f}(x):=\begin{cases}
f(x) & x\in U \\
0 & x\notin U
\end{cases}
$$
This means that, for instance, for a locally defined function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ and a bump function $\psi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\operatorname{supp}(\psi)\subset U$, we may always extend $\psi f$ in this manner to a smooth function $\widetilde{\psi f}:M\to\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes outside of $U$. Frequently this step is left implicit in various constructions involving partitions of unity.